# Four hand tiled squares demonstrating a Pythagorean Quadruple

Tags: no-computers, combinatorics, tiling, polyomino

Demonstrating the Pythagorean Quadruple

$6\times6 + 6\times6 + 7\times7 = 11\times11$

Using the pieces shown in the $11\times11$ square:

The objective:

1. Arrange the pink pieces (four enneominoes) into a $6\times6$
2. Arrange the blue pieces (six hexominoes) into a $6\times6$
3. Arrange the orange pieces (seven heptominoes) into a $7\times7$
4. Arrange all 17 pieces into a $11\times11$ but with no like colours touching, even at a corner.

All four tilings are unique. Hand tiling puzzle please, a computer will just spoil it for you. Flipping pieces is allowed.

[image]

Comment: Are we certain the third task is possible? I have been trying off and on for a while and am getting terribly close, but never exact.

Comment: Yes flipping of pieces is allowed. Added to puzzle statement.

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer - finished Task 1

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Sooo much NSFW! But thanks anyway :)

---

Task 1

> [image]

---

Task 2

> [image]

---

Task 3

> [image]

---

Task 4 - not solved yet.

Comment: Beautifully illustrated! Go for the last one! +1

Answer (score 2):

Like @Omega Krypton I have solved one part, Task 2:

> [image: Solution]